# SVN include mergeinfo in commits via CLI

Tags: bash, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I did a bash script to merge two different branches (with the same previous tree) and for some reason, I am still missing the mergeinfo. Is there any parameter to pass to the svn CLI in order to include this option?

Here my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source=$1
target=$2
inputFile=$3
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "you need to pass 3 parameter!"
    echo "usage: $0 source target inputFile"
    exit 1
fi 
cd $target
while IFS= read -r line
do
  IFS=' ' read -r id string <<< "$line"
  echo "Revision $id, message $string" 
  svn update
  svn merge -c $id $source
  if [ -z "$(svn status | grep -P '^(?=.{0,6}C)')" ]; then
    echo "No conflicts, proceeding to commit revision $id"
    svn commit * -m "Merge revision $id from $source: $string"
  else 
    echo "Conflicts, terminating the merge with id $id"
    svn revert *
    exit 1
  fi
done < "$inputFile"
```